# I'm having trouble installing this Add-On (Speedsculpt for Blender v2.79b)

Tags: add-on, installation

[image]
[image]
[image]

I am trying to install the add-on SpeedSculpt and I keep getting an error.

Steps I took:
Files -> user preferences -> Install Add-on from file -> clicked on '3D view:SpeedSculpt' and got an error as shown in the third photo.

I'm also not sure if I need to do anything with my license key. I havn't been able to find any info on this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to install a Blender 2.80 add-on in Blender 2.79?

Comment: Oh the on the website where I bought this add-on it said it supported both 2.79b and 2.8. Thank you for pointing that out i guess ill get blender 2.8 beta version and try it there

Comment: In the first picture you marked both files, so I guess you tried to install both files. You only need one file, the one I pointed out. The other file is for Blender 2.80, because it has 2.80 in the name.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly now :)